# V8 lazy generation of stack traces seems to cause an infinite loop in the vows library

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, node-inspector, vows

I spent some time debugging a strange infinite loop problem in a NodeJS testsuite. It only happens under rare conditions but I can reproduce it when I attach to the chrome debugger.

I think it has to do with V8's handling of [stack traces in exceptions](https://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/JavaScriptStackTraceApi) and a extension that the [vows library](http://vowsjs.org/) did to the `AssertionError` object (vows added an `toString` method). I could also be mistaken, so I wanted to ask whether my understanding of V8's implementation is correct.

Here is a minimal example to reproduce the error:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/flatiron/vows.git
$ cd vows && npm install && npm install should

$ cat > example.js
var should = require('should');
var error = require('./lib/assert/error.js');

try {
  'x'.should.be.json;
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.toString());
}

// without debug, it should fail as expected
$ node example.js
expected 'x' to have property 'headers' // should.js:61

// now with debug
$ node-inspector &
$ node --debug-brk example.js

// 1) open http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 in Chrome
// 2) set breakpoint at lib/assert/error.js#79 (the toString method)
// 3) Resume script execution (F8)
```

Now the program ends up in an infinite loop: the `toString` method (added by the vows library) is called again and again when `this.stack` is accessed in the regexp on line 83.

```
require('assert').AssertionError.prototype.toString = function () {
var that = this, // line 79: breakpoint
    source;

if (this.stack) {
    source = this.stack.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.(?:js|coffee))(:\d+):\d+/); // line 83: infinite loop takes place here (however, this.stack is undefined)
}
```

When I inspect `this` in the debugger, it shows that it is an `AssertionError` but its `stack` property is `undefined`. However, when I hover with the mouse over it, it shows the actual stack trace.

I assume this phenomena is caused by the laziness optimization of V8. It only computes the stack trace on demand. In doing so, it interferes with the added `toString` method of vows. The `toString` method again accesses the stack trace (`this.stack`), so the loop continues.

**Is that conclusion correct? If so, is there a way to patch the vows code, so it works with V8 (or can I at least report it as a bug in the vows project)?**

I'm using node v0.10.28 under Ubuntu.

**Update: Simplified example without vows**

Here is a simplified version. It no longer depends on vows, but instead I have only copied the relevant parts of its `toString` extension:

```
var should = require('should');

require('assert').AssertionError.prototype.toString = function () {
  var that = this,
    source;

  if (this.stack) {
    source = this.stack.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.(?:js|coffee))(:\d+):\d+/);
  }

  return '<dummy-result>';
};

try {
  'x'.should.be.json;
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.toString());
}

// expected result (without debug mode)
$ node example.js
<dummy-result>
```

In debug mode, the recursion takes place in the `if` statement.

**Update: Even simplier version with ReferenceError**

```
ReferenceError.prototype.toString = function () {
  var that = this,
    source;

  if (this.stack) {
    source = this.stack.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.(?:js|coffee))(:\d+):\d+/);
  }

  return '<dummy-result>';
};

try {
  throw new ReferenceError('ABC');
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.toString());
}
```

(I also create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ctew5/) example, but I cannot reproduce the infinite loop there, only with node.)

Comment: Can you create a self contained example that doesn't use vows?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, I was able to reproduce the same behavior by just using its toString method. I also removed the non-relevant parts, only the recursion is left.

Comment: What about `should.js`? Ideally, I'd love to see this problem isolated to the point it's reproducable without it (and to be even bolder, in the browser by every reader inside jsfiddle).

Comment: What about `
ReferenceError.prototype.toString = function () {
  var that = this,
    source;

  if (this.stack) {
    source = this.stack.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.(?:js|coffee))(:\d+):\d+/);
  }

  return '<dummy-result>';
};

try {
  foobarbaz;
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.toString());
}`

Comment: When I modify ReferenceError, it's normal behavior (the exception is thrown) and no infinite loop. AssertionError is the exception thrown by "should". I will try to simplify the example further by replace the "should" part by the actual throw.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum OK, now I understood what you meant. It is quite simple to reproduce it with a simplified ReferenceError example. I will update my post.

Comment: Major apologies, this reproduces just fine with the node debugger. I forgot to step into -_-.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Congratulations, you have found a bug in V8!

Yep, that's definitely a bug in the V8 version in that version of node.

The code in the version of V8 your version of Node uses code that looks something like:

```
function FormatStackTrace(error, frames) {
  var lines = [];
  try {
    lines.push(error.toString());
  } catch (e) {
    try {
      lines.push("<error: " + e + ">");
    } catch (ee) {
      lines.push("<error>");
    }
 }
```

Here is the actual code from the version [NodeJS uses](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10.28-release/deps/v8/src/messages.js#L1053-L1063).

The fact it's doing `error.toString()` itself is causing the loop, `this.stack` accesses `FormatStackTrace` which in turn is doing `.toString()`. Your observation is correct.

If that's any comfort, that code looks very different in newer versions of V8. In Node 0.11, [**this bug is already fixed**](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.11.13-release/deps/v8/src/messages.js#L1095-L1109).

Here is the [commit that fixed it](https://chromiumcodereview.appspot.com/11377158) commited A year and a half ago by [Vyacheslav Egorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/662844/vyacheslav-egorov).

#### What you can do about it?

Well, your options are limited, but since this is for debugging anyway, can always prevent the second iteration and stop the loop:

```
ReferenceError.prototype.toString = function () {
  var source;
  if(this.alreadyCalled) return "ReferenceError";
  this.alreadyCalled = true;
  if (this.stack) {
    source = this.stack.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.(?:js|coffee))(:\d+):\d+/);
  }

  return '<dummy-result>';
};
```

Does not exhibit the same issue. There is not much more you could do without access to the core code.

Comment: Cool. Currently, I have no access to unstable node, so I cannot test it against 0.11 (maybe I can do that later). Do you think that I should file a bug report, so the patch can be backported to stable node 0.10.x?

Comment: I seriously doubt there is any chance they'll backport it since it doesn't affect them very much, vows itself has not been updated in 9 months. I think a dirty hack to fix it would be to override its `.toString()` yourself, with a boolean "already called" flag. Nice catch by the way.

Comment: I opened an issue in node just in case though :)

Comment: Thanks, I also opened an issue in vows as a warning if you use vows (or easy-api) and "should" together: https://github.com/flatiron/vows/issues/303.